# Complex t in the Argument of the Zeta Function

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, riemann-zeta

In $\zeta (s) $, $s = \sigma + ti $, where $t $ is a real number, what would become of the zeta function if $t $ were to be complex?

> Does there exist a proof that $\zeta (\sigma + (a+bi)i) $ cannot be
>   zero, where $(a+bi) = t $, $a $ is real, and b is either real or
>   complex?
>
> Does  $t $ have to be a real number for $\zeta (\sigma+ti) $ to
>   vanish? Please provide a reference for the proof of this.

Comment: Well, $\zeta(\sigma + (a + bi)i) = \zeta(\sigma - b + ai) = \zeta(\sigma' + t' i)$ for different values of $\sigma'$ and $t'$. It's the same exact problem.

Comment: Where can I read about that?

Comment: Any elementary complex analysis book. This is just arithmetic of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s=\sigma+ti$ and $s_2=\sigma_2+t_2i$ be two complex numbers and $\sigma, \sigma_2, t, t_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then

\begin{align}
s' &= \sigma+(s_2)i \\
   &= \sigma\sigma_2+\sigma t_2 i + t\sigma_2 i-tt_2 \\
   &= (\sigma\sigma_2-tt_2)+(\sigma t_2+t\sigma_2)i
\end{align}

is still a complex number.